# How to post formatted message into a channel with Slack API

Tags: python, json, slack, slack-api

I have a json formatted message like [this](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22*bold*%20%60code%60%20_italic_%20~strike~%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22markdownbot%22%2C%22mrkdwn%22%3Atrue%7D), I want to post this message into Slack with [Slack postMessage API](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test). Pasting the json string into `text` section would not work, how/where should I input that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the link you posted, you'll need to generate an API token for your slack account. After that, choose a channel to post the message and put

```
*bold* `code` _italic_ ~strike~
```

next to the "text" field. The message should be posted in your slack channel.

Since you're using python, you can use the [python slack api](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) to do this. The code would then be

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
slack_client = SlackClient(API TOKEN)
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=CHANNEL ID, text="*bold* `code` _italic_ ~strike~", as_user=True)
```

Comment: That's true, but I want to post the formatted text `{
    "text": "*bold* `code` _italic_ ~strike~",
    "username": "markdownbot",
    "mrkdwn": true
}`, for instance, in which I can enable/disable markdown feature.